# How to export obiee12c users with application roles?

Tags: oracle, etl, obiee

I have taken backup of RPD and Catalog of OBIEE12c using exportarchieve utility as a bar file. After importing bar file in another server using importarchieve utility, I found that users and application roles did not import. So, how can I export and import obiee12c users and application roles?

Answer (score 0):

What EXACT commands did you use on what EXACT version? They changed over the lifespan of the product and you may just be using wrong calls:

https://datacadamia.com/dat/obiee/admin/12c/bar

Answer (score 0):

exportarchieve utility does not export users in bar file. You need to export security data (i.e., users and applications roles) to a file separately. The following is the way to export security data to a file.

Step 1: Login to the weblogic console using admin user.

Step 2: Select Security Realms (for example myrealm)

Step 3: Expand migration tab then export tab

Step 4: Provide export directory name in "Export Directory on Server Filed"

Step 5: Save

The security data (i.e., users and applications roles) is saved in a file in the location you specified.

Comment: Users shouldn't be held in the WLS-embedded LDAP, but rather be sourced from a proper LDAP, MSAD or a full-blown SSO solution.

Answer (score 0):

Both the other answers are correct but not complete.
Application roles are part of EM and are included in a BAR file export.

Users / Groups are in Weblogic and are not included in a BAR file export.

People often get Weblogic Groups and EM Application Roles mixed up but if your application roles are not showing up in EM then look in the logs as they should be part of the JAZN data.   (The BAR is actually a zip file and you should be able to unzip it and look in the authmodel folder to check you have the XML definitions in there).

When importing you do have the option to skip the role definitions (`noauthorization` switch) so just check you aren't specifying that.